# Type of Column In the Information Schema COLUMNS Table

Tags: mariadb

In MariaDB, what are the type of the fields in *Information Schema COLUMNS* Table ?
I can't find it in the [mariadb documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-columns-table/)

Comment: You should be able to see them in phpMyAdmin, does yours show the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/265677)

Comment: Interesting Fiddle link :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly haha fixed xD

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm stupid. Obviously:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" AND TABLE_NAME = "COLUMNS";
```